# Get postfix to forward root's mail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I have an Ubuntu server running postfix. It is not the mail server for my domain.

Whenever a cron job runs for root, the output mail is not delivered locally, instead it gets sent to root@mydomain.com via the main mail server. This is not what I want.

I want mail for root to either be delivered locally or forwarded to anothermail@anotherdomain.com.

I've tried modifying both `~root/.forward` and `/etc/aliases` (and running newaliases), but nothing helps (I guess these files are only checked when postfix tries to deliver mail locally).

What can I do?

This is `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = linux1.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = linux1.mydomain.com, localhost.linux1.mydomain.com, localhost
relayhost = my.isps.relayhost.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

**Edit:**

When sending mail to root, this goes into `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Mar  7 09:39:17 linux1 postfix/pickup[31381]: F3B9C98025E: uid=1000 from=<ct>
Mar  7 09:39:18 linux1 postfix/cleanup[31556]: F3B9C98025E: message-id=<20130307083917.F3B9C98025E@linux1.mydomain.com>
Mar  7 09:39:18 linux1 postfix/qmgr[28525]: F3B9C98025E: from=<ct@mydomain.com>, size=283, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  7 09:39:18 linux1 postfix/smtp[31558]: F3B9C98025E: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=my.isps.relayhost.com[<IP address omitted>]:25, delay=0.72, delays=0.19/0.02/0.27/0.25, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as A97F5D8126)
Mar  7 09:39:18 linux1 postfix/qmgr[28525]: F3B9C98025E: removed
```

The name "ct" is my user name. I generated the above text through this command:

`echo test | mail -s test root`

The content of `/etc/mailname` is:

```
mydomain.com
```

The contents of `/etc/aliases` is:

```
root: anothermail@anotherdomain.com
postmaster:    root
```

where anothermail@anotherdomain.com is where I would like root's mail to be forwarded to.

The content of `/etc/hosts` actually surprises me a little:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 linux1.mylinux.mydomain.com linux1
```

where "mylinux" is the hostname of a host operating system under which linux1 runs as a virtual machine. I'm not sure how "mylinux" got in there. (But could this really be the reason for my problem?)

Comment: Could you provide us your postfix logs when you send a mail to root ?

Comment: I have done so in an edit to the original post.

Comment: Could you give us your /etc/mailname and /etc/aliases files ? Check if /etc/hosts contains the linux1.mydomain.com assigned to 127.0.1.1

Comment: I have added the information to the original post.

Comment: According to your logs, the mail has been correctly sent out to your isp smtp relay.

I'd ask them (isp) to check my.isps.relayhost.com[<IP address omitted>] logs for any clue (antispam, error, ...) about the problem.

Comment: Actually the logs show the email being delivered to the wrong address. He wants it delivered to anothermail@anotherdomain.com, not root@mydomain.com.

Comment: This is for Dom: I turns out that the problem arises because of the difference between the hostname in `/etc/mailname` and the contents of `/etc/hosts`. I fixed that, and now the mail works nicely.
Thank you, Dom. If you could write this as a proper answer, I will acknowledge it as a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As ususal, check your logs.

In your case, the postfix daemon thinks the mail is not for it and sends it without using `/etc/aliases`

First check your `/etc/hosts` file : it should have your machine name corresponding to `127.0.1.1`, like this:

```
127.0.1.1  linux1.mydomain.com  linux1
```

Check your `/etc/mailname` too, and it should be consistent.

Check your `/etc/aliases` to see if root (user) is sent to another user, and redo the `newaliases` command.

And it should work!

Comment: Should that be `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: You can have any address in 127.0.0.0/8, so 127.0.0.1 works well too

Comment: I had a similar problem while I only wanted to use a smarthost relay to send mails out: "myhostname" had to be "localhost". Anything else skipped the aliases file.

Answer (score 9):

If `mydestination` is empty or does not contain `$myhostname` then the `/etc/aliases` will be ignored because postfix thinks the email is not a local delivery and will therefore not apply the local aliases. So, leave `mydestination` at the default (`postconf -d mydestination` or remove it from `main.cf`) and the logs should show the `to=<...>` as your aliased address.

Comment: I'm using an external mail server and `mydestination` must be empty. Otherwise no mail is sent.

Answer (score 4):

In some circumstances, (i.e. where all mail gets relayed to an external system), it's easier to just set the `MAILTO` variable in root's crontab to a real email address. This should pretty much bypass traditional delivery to root and just make it go where you want.

```
# Root's crontab
MAILTO=someone@example.com
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/somescript
```

Comment: geniuous! This should be the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with opening of `/root/.forward` by postfix daemon, at least on hardened system (I didn't dig into it). Despite:

```
# ls -ld / /root /root/.forward
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root  236 Dec  4 00:02 /
dr-xr-x--x. 13 root root 4096 Jan  8 17:45 /root
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   30 Jan  8 14:51 /root/.forward
```

Child of postfix daemon is not able to access .forward:

```
7603  open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 16
7603  fstat(16, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1227, ...}) = 0
7603  mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f86854fb000
7603  read(16, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1227
7603  close(16)                         = 0
7603  munmap(0x7f86854fb000, 4096)      = 0
7603  geteuid()                         = 89
7603  getegid()                         = 89
7603  geteuid()                         = 89
7603  setresuid(-1, 0, -1)              = 0
7603  setresgid(-1, 0, -1)              = 0
7603  setgroups(1, [0])                 = 0
7603  lstat("/root/.forward", 0x7ffc03f84750) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I didn't have time to dig into it...
Appending entry to `/etc/aliases` followed by `newaliases` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case you happen to have set up destination domain filtering in `/etc/postfix/transport` then you need to add the subdomain of your machine to the allowed domains list. And in case you are using some VPS and the hosting provider has assigned some automatic internal domain name to your system, then you may need to add this too.

For example, if you had:

```
mydomain.com                :
anotherdomain.com           :
*                           discard:
```

Update it to:

```
uvn-12-34.am01.hostingvs.eu :
linux1.mylinux.mydomain.com :
mydomain.com                :
anotherdomain.com           :
*                           discard:
```

Without this update the line
`root: anothermail@anotherdomain.com`
in
`/etc/aliases` or a similar one in `.forward`
does not have the desired end effect since the message is discarded before being forwarded.